# Using ES6 module in node-red

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-red, es6-modules

I have created a program that creates company profiles by extracting data from several rest api's, web scraping and so on.
I Just came across node-red and I wanted to use it to visualize the steps that my code does when data flows through and gets enriched.

The code is written as an ES6 module and I use: `import { myfunction} from "mymodule";`
I also use the module in the nextjs part of my system so I can't just rewrite it to javascript.

I'd like to use functions from my library/module in node-red. Tried to set `"type": "module"` in package.json  But that did not work. 
There must be some best practices to do this. I find it hard to believe that es6 modules cannot be used with node-red.

Comment: Used where? in the Function node or in a custom node?

Comment: I need to use it in a function node. eg:
import { myfunction} from "mymodule";
myresult = await myfunction();
console.log("result from myfunction",myresult);

Comment: And you've read this part of the docs? https://nodered.org/docs/user-guide/writing-functions#loading-additional-modules If so [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67601855/edit) the question to show what you've tried and explain what and how it didn't work